# java.util.concurrent : calculating primes

Tags: java, multithreading, primes, concurrency

I'm new to the package [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). I've created the following program testing if a number is a prime using a multi and a monothreaded strategy.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class IsPrime
        implements Runnable
    {
    private static final long UPPER_BOUND=100000;
    long value;//the number observed
    private IsPrime(long value)
        {
        this.value=value;
        }
    /** returns wether value is a prime number (simple and stupid method ) */
    private boolean isAPrimeNumber()
        {
        if(value==1 || value==2) return true;
        if(value%2L==0) return false;
        for(long i=3;i< value;++i)
            {
            if(this.value%i==0) return false;
            }
        return true;
        }

    @Override
    /** calls isAPrimeNumber */
    public void run()
        {
        boolean result=isAPrimeNumber();
        //if(result) System.out.println("["+this.value+"]");
        }

    /** loop from 3 to UPPER_BOUND, multithreaded */
    private static long loopMT() 
        {
        long now=System.currentTimeMillis();
        ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 

        for(long i=3;i< UPPER_BOUND;i+=2)
            {
            service.submit(new IsPrime(i));
            }
        service.shutdown();
        return System.currentTimeMillis()-now;
        }

    /** loop from 3 to UPPER_BOUND, NOT multithreaded */
    private static long loop() 
        {
        long now=System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(long i=3;i< UPPER_BOUND;i+=2)
            {
            new IsPrime(i).run();
            }
        return System.currentTimeMillis()-now;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        long n1=IsPrime.loop();
        long n2=IsPrime.loopMT();
        System.out.println(""+n1+" >>> "+n2);   
        }
    }
```

for the method **loopMT**, is it the correct way to use the classes of the package **java.util.concurrent** ? Is there another, (safer, more elegant) way to write this program ? Can I use System.out in a multithreaded environement ?

Many thanks for your suggestions

Pierre

Comment: Why are you implementing `Runnable` instead of `Callable<Boolean>`?

Comment: I don't really need a return value. In my true program (not this one) I only need to print out the result of a time-consuming process. This is why I commented out the System.out in 'void run(void)'

Comment: The title of your question is misleading: I thought it was about finding an optimized way to compute primes on multi-cores CPUs :)  Then something is not clear to me: do you want the System.out printed primes to be printed in order or not?

Comment: no. I want to find the best Java way to manage a pool of threads(?) that would perform a time-consuming calculation and would print the result at the end. The values are independent so, the order of the results does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is currently written `loopMT` is not waiting for the submitted tasks to complete.

You have a few options:

- Call `awaitTermination()` to wait for all primality tests to complete, writing the results to `System.out` as you are currently doing.
- Change the interface from `Runnable` to `Callable<Boolean>` or maybe `Callable<Map.Entry<Long, Boolean>>` and use `service.invokeAll()` (then you will get all results returned at once.)
- Store the results in a synchronized `Map` and read it when all the primality tests have completed
- Have the `run` method send the results to a `BlockingQueue` or `SynchronousQueue` and have the `loopMT` method loop fetching the results from the queue and printing them.  This is the option I would prefer.
- Use a queue indirectly, via a `CompletionService`.

Comment: `SynchronousQueue` is more like channel in fact, I doubt that it is appropriate here. And why use synchronized map but not `ConcurrentMap`? Its throughput is much better in most cases.

Comment: Yes a `SynchronousQueue` is a channel and that is what you want, if you have another thread blocked reading it, which is what I am suggesting.  `ConcurrentMap` is fine (though you don't need its extra methods.)

Answer (score 2):

As `System.out` is an instance of `PrintStream` it is thread-safe. So it is fine for training examples. But generally output from different threads doesn't seem like a good idea to me. It's better to have dedicated output thread that accepts requests for output asynchronously.

Probably, I'd rather implemented `Callable<Boolean>` as finnw suggested, otherwise I see no reason in `IsPrime` class except of CPU consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Since this calculation is likely CPU bound, there is no advantage to running more threads than you have CPU cores. Extra threads after that only add to overhead.